# Mapping string based on first letter

Tags: python

I have a list of items that I want to obfuscate based on the letter of the item's name. For example:

```
ABC_Classified
BXY_Classified
ZX_Classified
```

Key:

```
A -> Adam
B -> Bale
Z -> Talking
```

Result:

```
ABC_Classified ==> Adam
BXY_Classified ==> Bale
ZX_Classified ==> Talking
```

The first way to do this, which would be extremely repetitious, would be having 26 `if/elif` statements for this.

What would be the best and most concise way to accomplish the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary?

```
mapping = {
    'A': 'Adam',
    'B': 'Bale',
    'Z': 'Talking'
    # etc...
}

name = mapping[your_string[0]]
```

If the lookup fails, it'll throw a KeyError

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary to map letters to names, then catch `KeyError` for nonexistent keys and `IndexError` in case an empty string is passed in.

```
names = {
    'A': 'Adam',
    'B': 'Bale',
    ...
    'Z': 'Talking'
}

def obfuscate(s):
    try:
        return names[s[0]]
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        return None
```

Answer (score 1):

I must say, I'm not sure exactly what the purpose of this obfuscation is, but is this anything like what you're looking for?

```
# the name strings
names = ["ABC_Classified","BXY_Classified","ZX_Classified"]

# the letter-to-obfuscated string mappings
key = { "A":"Adam", "B":"Bale", "Z":"Talking" } 

# doing a lookup
key[ names[0][0] ] # ABC_Classified ==> Adam

# optionally create a new, direct mapping
dict( [ (obf, key[ obf[0] ]), for obf in names ] )
# {'BXY_Classified': 'Bale', 'ABC_Classified': 'Adam', 'ZX_Classified': 'Talking'}
```